# Counting the Number of Characters in a File Using Bash and Assigning to Variable

Tags: bash, shell

I need to loop through a text file provided and count the number of characters in the file.  The file will only contain one word that I am supposed to analyze.  So basically, I just need to know the length of the word.  I want to assign the length to a variable that I have defined in the bash file.  Here's what I have(ignore the other if statement at the end, I know that it is working properly.  I just need help with the while loop):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
COUNT=0
NUMCHARS=0
while IFS= read -rN1 char; do
  if [[ "$char" == $'[a-zA-Z0-9#$+%@]' ]]; then
    let NUMCHARS=NUMCHARS+1
  fi
done < "$FILE"
if [ -r "${FILE}" ]; then
  if /bin/egrep -q [09] $FILE ; then
    let COUNT=COUNT+5
  fi
fi
echo $COUNT
echo $NUMCHARS
```

Comment: Why not use the `wc` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The file will only contain one word

In that case you can do:

```
# read the whole file in a variable
w="$(<"$FILE")"

# get the length
echo "length is: ${#w}"
```

**Option 2:** Using `wc`

```
len=$(( $(wc -c < "$FILE") - 1 ))
```